# How to increase jenkins build number automatically?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-scriptler

How to increase jenkins build number automatically or by using shell script??
For now i am doing the same using configure option, and increasing manually. i want to do it automatically.

Comment: It does auto increment it on every triggered build. What do you mean by "For now i am doing the same using configure option, and increasing manually" ? The environment variable "BUILD_NUMBER" provided by jenkins will display that for you in the build logs if you echo it.

Comment: @Mayur two thing are here. 1. when build going to fails then also build number going to increase. 2. i am using plugin "Invoke Top-Level Maven Targets" inside this plugin suppose i am keeping version=50. if it fails then next time i am not going to keep 51, it will be 50 only unlit build is not success. so this number i am keeping manually. i want ti automatically. if i am using "BUILD_NUMBER" inside the same plugin then it will be increment even in failure also. i want it increment only in case of Build Success.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Jenkins maintains the build number in a file called as  nextbuildnumber. Everytime a build kicks in it auto increments that number. If you want you can control that via shell script login that will check for your build result. If build passes (you may want to check exit code), let it increment that number , else reset it to old one. Also, you may want to purge directories/workspace for that build. Login into jenkins slave to understand the internals.

Comment: There are ways to increase that number, but at no point can you change to match an already existing build.

Answer (score 22):

What you are asking for (i.e. keeping the build number same between multiple jobs) is simply **impossible** in Jenkins. This is done by design (as noted by Jenkins creator himself): [`"[JENKINS] assumes that the build number is unique and monotonic."`](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Set-custom-build-number-td379762.html). You can change it to a higher value, but changing it to same number will outright break Jenkins and is therefore not possible.

Build *run* number is just that: a **run** number.
It is supposed to be sequential.
 It is **not** a version number in any way.

There are several ways to get versioning information into the build history however.

**[Description Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin)**
This is what I use. It doesn't change the *build number*, but rather the *description*, which is done automatically. Furthermore, since this is a description, it can also be modified manually at any time.

This is what it looks like:
[image: Description Setter build number]
Note that builds `#50` and `#51` actually have the same version `1.3.0.394376`.
In that version string, the `1.3.0` is the current release number, as determined by the project properties, while the `394376` is actually an SVN revision number, obtained from `$SVN_REVISION_1` build variable. So every time there is a new commit in SVN, I get a new revision number. But if there are no commits and the job is rebuilt for whatever reason (like in `#50` and `#51`), my version number remains same, as there was no *code* change.

The way I have it configured is:

- Download [Description Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin)
- Somewhere in your **Build Steps**, output your version *
- I simply have:
  `echo Version is: ${internalVersionNumberFromWherever}.${SVN_REVISION_1}`
- Next setup **Post-build Action** with **Set build description**
- Setup **Regular expression** to extract the version number from the console:
  `Version is: (.*)`
- Leave everything else blank, and the whatever RegEx picks up in `(.*)` will be used as description.
- Alternatively, you can further set **Description** text as `Build - \1`. Where `\1` is a reference to first group `(.*)` from the RegEx.
- At any time you can *manually* change the description of the run by selecting the build run from the build history, and clicking *"edit description"* link on the right (provided that user has *"Update"* permissions configured).

** Note that if your build fails before the step that outputs the version text, the description setter plugin will not be able to pick it up. If you always want to see the version, then setup the display of version number as the very first step.*

[**Build Name Setter plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin)
This plugin will actually change the *build number*
[image]
**However** remember the limitation that each build number has to be **unique**.
Best way to ensure that is to add `${BUILD_NUMBER}` to whatever arbitrary number that you want (like in the image above). This way you can have builds numbers like `50.123` and then `50.124` where `50` is your *version* while `123` and `124` are sequential build *run* numbers, and Jenkins makes sure of keeping the `${BUILD_NUMBER}` unique.

Finally, there is the **[Version Number plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin)** which I haven't personally tried, but it may help you.